# Using Electron 10 with Requirejs in renderer returns an error

Tags: electron, requirejs

I have been using requirejs (latest) with Electron 9, but since Electron 10 when including it in the **renderer** script I see the following error:

```
node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global, Buffer) { return function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { #!/usr/bin/env node

                                                                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:88:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:261:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:10)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1108:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1173:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:992:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12694)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:19)
```

****To reproduce:****

**in main.js**

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  })

  //and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
```

**in index.html**:

```
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

**in renderer.js**:

```
var r = require('requirejs');
```

Comment: To ask why your error occurred is a good place to start! If you could elaborate on your question by including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would help others to answer you. Also try not to define your question as _"I have this problem"_ but rather _"I have this goal"_, that will help people who are familiar with the "goal" topic to find your question :)